# Weird issue with casting substring to integer

Tags: c#, sqlite, casting, substring, int32

I'm getting a weird issue with substringing. Apparently the string I get can't be cast into an Int32 for some odd reason. The error message I get when I try doing that is "input string is not in correct format". Because of this, I can't insert these values into the Database either.

Here's the code...

```
string width = GetMetadata(filename, 162); //returns "1280 pixels"
string height = GetMetadata(filename, 164); //returns "700 pixels"
width = width.Substring(0, width.IndexOf(' ')); //returns "1280"
height = height.Substring(0, height.IndexOf(' ')); //returns "700"

//test: "System.Convert.ToInt32(width)" will fail, giving error "input string was not in correct format"
//doing the above on "width" yields the same result

//fails, giving error "no such column: 1280" (underlying database is sqlite)            
Database.NonQuery("INSERT INTO image VALUES (" + fileid + ", " + width + ", " + height + ")");
```

Comment: You've put a breakpoint in there and absolutely verified that the values returned by `GetMetadata()` are what you expect? No extraneous spaces? No tabs or other incorrect whitespace? Because with the values "1280 pixels" and "700 pixels", that code works fine.

Comment: @Carson : Yes, the values in the comments are exactly what I'm getting. I'll double check and post back if this is not the case.

Comment: First of all - better to use parameters when working with database. What is the current culture on development machine?

Comment: It works fine when you assign width="1280 pixels". I agree with Carson63000 - double check the result of GetMetadata.

Comment: Setting the starting index to 1 seems to have fixed the issue. There must have been whitespace or some other character there that I didn't see before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all the normal reasons - primarily avoiding leaving data conversions to the database, and preventing SQL injection attacks - I would suggest that you perform the parsing to a number in C#, and then use a [parameterized query](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/83.aspx) to talk to SQLite.

In this case, that will make it a lot easier to debug - either .NET will fail to parse the string as well (in which case it's likely to be a problem with your data) or it will work, and you won't need to worry about what conversions database was performing.

EDIT: I've just seen your comment saying that `Convert.ToInt32` fails as well. That's a pretty clear indication that it's the data which is causing a problem.

I'd expect your code to look something like this:

```
string widthText = GetMetadata(filename, 162);
string heightText = GetMetadata(filename, 164);
widthText = width.Substring(0, width.IndexOf(' ')).Trim();
heightText = height.Substring(0, height.IndexOf(' ')).Trim();

int width = int.Parse(widthText, CulutureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int height = int.Parse(widthText, CulutureInfo.InvariantCulture);

using (SQLiteCommand cmd = Database.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO image VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(fileid);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(width);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(height);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note that the `Trim` call will remove any leading spaces, which it seems was the cause of the problem.

Comment: The problem has been solved, so I'm going off on a tangent here. Are there any advantages to using parameterized queries instead of normal queries besides protection against injection attacks? At the moment, I'm only using parameterized queries where user input needs to be inserted into the database.

Comment: @rafale: It separates *code* (SQL) from *data* (values). It means you can see the data separately from the code really cleanly... as well as avoiding conversions taking place in the database when you've already got the data in a non-string form in your code. This is particularly important when transferring something like a date, where there are obviously several different formats for representing dates.

Comment: I consider it bad practice to use non-parameterized queries when not dealing with user input.  Then, every time you look at the query you have to ask yourself, "Hey, this is non-parameterized.  Am I sure this isn't going to ever see user input, even in the future?"

Answer (score 0):

There may be some stray whitespaces in the string variables `width` and `height`. Invoke `Trim()` method on the strings before casting them into integers:

```
width = width.Trim();
height = height.Trim();
```

Hope this helps. Let us know.